# Subview of customized UIButton wasn't at the right postition

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I added a `subView` to my customized `UIButton`. Then I created a button subclass to my customized `UIButton` from `Storyboard`, but the bounds of the `subView` wasn't set correctly.

**Expected:**

[image]

**What I got instead:**

[image]

Code of my customized `UIButton`, quite simple:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class RoundShadowButton: UIButton {

    var backLayer: UIView!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        backLayer = UIView()

        //add the subView
        backLayer?.bounds = bounds
        backLayer!.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        backLayer?.layer.masksToBounds = false
        backLayer!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3).CGColor
        backLayer!.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        backLayer.clipsToBounds = false
        addSubview(backLayer)

        //add shadow to layer of UIButton
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 32, 9, 32)
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.5)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        clipsToBounds = false
    }
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will override method "func layoutSubviews()" to set frame of your backLayer subview, something like this

```
override func layoutSubviews() 
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    backLayer.frame = bounds
}
```

Why did you do setup in "drawRect(rect: CGRect)" no in the "init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" or "func awakeFromNib()"?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't override `func layoutSubviews()` but changed `backLayer.bounds = bounds` to `backLayer.frame = bounds` and everything is fine. For your question, I do setup in `drawRect` because I want the changes I make show up in Storyboard.